# How can I utilize SharePoint to set up an office training library inventory?

Tags: 2010

How can I set up a Training Materials Library for a large corporate office? A dozen people would need access to record the materails they would be using from the inventory. It would need an alert option for when an item's inventory reached a reorder mark.